# Migrating from Office 2007 to 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, migration, microsoft-office-2010, pst

What is the correct way to migrate Office 2007 PST from one machine to a fresh installation with Office 2010?

Several articles around the web seem to indicate that merely copying the `Outlook.pst` file to `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` would cause Outlook 2010 to use the file automagically.

But instead, after installation, Outlook 2010 insists on creating new accounts from scratch, and creates a separate `.pst` file somewhere inside `My Documents`.

I wanted to **avoid** importing from the old `.pst` file, because I wanted to get full data: accounts, mails and rules.

What should I actually do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook &
       %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.pst
2. Run the program for the first time, and exit the Startup Wizard; this will create the key in #1.
3. Restore #1.